# link new object to scene with python in 2.8

Tags: python, objects

In Python 2.8, I would like to create copies of the object 'CubeTemplate' but am having no luck.  I have reviewed every blender.stackexchange post on this subject ([this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135597/how-to-duplicate-an-object-in-2-8-via-the-python-api-without-using-bpy-ops-obje), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126257/2-8-how-to-duplicate-collection-without-keeping-it-linked), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58175/python-duplicating-a-group-with-animation?rq=1) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/duplicating-non-primitive-mesh-with-python)) but cannot get them to work - either they don't apply or the sample code throws errors (perhaps because it was pre 2.8).

The code below throws this error:

> AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'

```
for x in range(1, 3):
    bpy.data.objects['CubeTemplate'].select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['CubeTemplate']
    me = bpy.context.object.data # use current object's data
    me_copy = me.copy()
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new('CubeCopy'+str(x), me_copy)
    ob.location = (0, 0, x)
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.objects.link(ob)
    scene.update()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue with your code comes from an [api change](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API#Adding_Objects) in 2.80.
We no longer link objects to the scene, they have to be linked to a collection.

So all you have to do to make your script work is to change your scene references to collections

You old code:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(ob)
scene.update()
```

Replace with this:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

Or shorter:

```
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

Or if you wanted to link the objects to a specific collection you'd do this with this line:

```
bpy.data.collections["Collection Name"].objects.link(ob)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Blender 2.79?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in 2.8:

```
import bpy
templateName = 'CubeTemplate'
template = bpy.data.objects[templateName]

for x in range(1, 3):
    template.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(x, 0, 0)})
    copy = bpy.data.objects[templateName + '.001']
    copy.name = 'CubeCopy' + str(x)

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Comment: DVed because it is better not to use ops. Plus it is just not needed for something simple like duplicating an object

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I assume that using ops is not so great because of some overhead/performance consideration? It _is_ the more easily learned route to accomplishing duplication since it's what prints in the Info window when manually performing the duplication.