# Python: Copied Object Not Showing in Outliner

Tags: python, outliner

When I copy an object using `bpy.context.active_object.copy()` the new object doesn't show up in the *Outliner* even though it appears when I `list()` objects in the Python shell.

Questions:

1. Is there a second step to get the object to show in the *Outliner*?
2. Or perhaps it's only copying the object's data? (If so, to what purpose?)
3. Are there no companion functions, ie: paste() and/or cut()? (Command line completion yields nothing.)

Note: `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()` makes a copy that *does* show up in the *Outliner*, so these questions aren't about how to make a working copy/duplicate. I want to understand the purpose of `copy()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Link it to a collection**

Prior to 2.8 a copied object required linking to the scene's objects collection.  For 2.8+ link it to a collection.

It will show in the outliner when collection is linked to a scene, or is the base scene collection.

The duplicate operator links the dupe to the context collection.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


ob = context.object.copy()
context.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

[link new object to scene with python in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145658/link-new-object-to-scene-with-python-in-2-8)

Comment: Thanks again, batFINGER. I was going to say, "You da man," but in this era, perhaps... "You da person," is more PC.