# Need to modernize my scripting, this bpy based script from 2.77 doesn't run in 2.92 so I can't post my main question yet

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I need to make a custom mesh, don't know how and want to post a question about it.

However before I do I want to run an example of something simple. I've been away *for several years*, this runs on 2.77.

**Question:** What are the changes to Blender that prevent this old script from running in the modern world, and how to change it so that it runs in 2.92 which I will start using now?

Once I can do this I can create an example on which to base my more challenging question.

---

runs in 2.77, fails in 2.92 with error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/your-name-here/Documents/NTHU/Blender/meshitest.blend/Text", line 25, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

[image: wiggly mesh]

```
import numpy as np
import bpy

x = 0.5 *np.arange(-8, 9)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x[2:-2])
Z = np.ones_like(X) -0.1
ny, nx = X.shape
X, Y, Z = [thing.flatten() for thing in (X, Y, Z)]
Z[::2] += 0.2
verts = list(zip(X, Y, Z))

faces = []
for i in range(ny-1):
    for j in range(nx-1):
        v1 = i*(nx) + j
        v2 = v1 + 1
        v3 = v2 + nx
        v4 = v3 - 1
        faces.append((v1, v2, v3, v4))

name = 'sqr'
me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)

bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)

bpy.data.objects[name].select = False
bpy.data.objects[name].select = True

bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

Comment: How to select an object: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132825/python-selecting-object-by-name-in-2-8

Comment: @brockmann the link in the answer answers my question in a much more direct and accessible way, but the answer in yours is of course more complete. *Thanks!*

Comment: I've just asked [Strategy for script-generating a buckled honeycomb lattice mesh (hex faces) for animating 2D materials?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/215079/5334)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question may be found in [this Q&A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145658/link-new-object-to-scene-with-python-in-2-8). Since 2.8, it seems that objects should be linked to **collections** instead of **scenes**.

old:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
```

new:

```
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

Comment: Yes this works nicely, thank you very much!